# TexBlock scrolling in Popup

Tags: c#, popup, windows-store-apps, scrollviewer

I have a problem with scrolling TextBlock text in popup (C#, Windows Store App).

I have a TextBlock in Popup. I need to be able to scroll text, when it is larger than popup size, but it does not scroll, it cuts out part of the text, that does not fit in.

I have tried this code:

```
<Popup>
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
<RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<TextBlock x:Name="PopupHeader" Grid.Row="0" Text="Header"/>
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
<TextBlock x:Name="PopupContent" Text="Main text" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" TextAlignment="Justify" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
</Popup>
```

I set TextBlock text, Popup and TextBlock height from code.
Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put height and widthin TextBlock.

```js
 <Popup  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                IsOpen="True">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock x:Name="PopupHeader"
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           Text="Header" />

                <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1"
                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="PopupContent"
                               Width="put width here" Height="put height here"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               Text="Somthing really long text here"
                               TextAlignment="Justify" />

                </ScrollViewer>

            </Grid>
        </Popup>
```

Comment: It is little bit complicated becase it is read only control . Refer this post .http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/09/08/creating-scrollable-textblock-for-wp7.aspx